# passing element id to function as parameter

Tags: javascript, html

this is my .js function

```
function validateSNo(inputtxt,elem){
            var SNoFormat = /^\d{6}$/;
            if (SNoFormat.test(inputtxt)){
                document.getElementById(elem).innerHTML = "";
                return true;
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById(elem).innerHTML = "This should only contain 6 numbers XXXXXX";
                return false;
            }
```

this is the html code

```
<label>Student No.</label>
                            <input type="text" name="sNo" size="6" maxlength="6" onblur="return validateSNo(document.FormStuReg.sNo.value,sNo-validation)" autofocus><span class="errorMsg">*</span>
                            <br>
                            <span class="errorMsg" id="sNo-validation"></span>
```

i want to display the validation message in the span area when an invalid input is detected.this code doesn't work..It works fine without the parameters when the function is written like this.

```
function validateSNo(){
        var SNoFormat = /^\d{6}$/;
        if (SNoFormat.test(document.FormStuReg.sNo.value)){
          document.getElementById("sNo-validation").innerHTML = "";
          return true;
        }
        else {
          document.getElementById("sNo-validation").innerHTML = "This should only contain 6 numbers XXXXXX";
          return false;
        }
      }
```

I have to use the same validation in few other places so its better if i can pass the values as parameters to single function or else i have to write the same function over n over again with different element id's.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle of the code working with no parameters?

Comment: i'm new to this web programming and this is my first web app..i dont know how to work with jsfiddle.sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the `onblur` attribute in your HTML.

```
onblur="return validateSNo(document.FormStuReg.sNo.value,sNo-validation)"
```

Notice that `sNo-validation` is not in quotation marks.  That means that it's interpreted as two variables: `sNo` and `validation`, which are undefined, and the `-` is interpreted as a minus sign.  Subtracting two undefined variables doesn't make sense, so that's why you get an error.

Just add quotation marks.  Since it's already inside quotation marks because it's an HTML attribute, use single quotes.

```
onblur="return validateSNo(document.FormStuReg.sNo.value, 'sNo-validation')"
```

Answer (score 0):

BTW, since you are using a scheme like *sNo* and *sNo-validation* then you don't need to pass the ID. I'll guess that `document.FormStuReg.sNo.value` is the input that the listener is on, so you can just pass a reference to the element using *this*:

```
<input ... name="sNo" ... onblur="return validateSNo(this)" ... >
```

And then in the function:

```
// element will reference the input
function validateSNo(element){
    var SNoFormat = /^\d{6}$/;

    if (SNoFormat.test(element.value)){

      // Use the element name to get the message element
      document.getElementById(element.name + "-validation").innerHTML = "";
      return true;
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById(element.name + "-validation").innerHTML = "This should only contain 6 numbers XXXXXX";
      return false;
    }
  }
```

and the *if..else* can use the [conditional ? : operator](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.12):

```
   document.getElementById(element.name + "-validation").innerHTML = SNoFormat.test(element.value)? '' : 'This should only contain 6 numbers XXXXXX';
```

Returning true or false from the listener has no effect whatever.

If you take this one step further, you can define the validation to run in a class value or *data-* attribute, then you don't need to pass anything. Just validate all form controls based on their class or *data-* values.